# Is there a way to manually set @@ROWCOUNT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this script to illustrate what I want:

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF
DECLARE @table TABLE(col1 INT IDENTITY(1,1), col2 INT)
INSERT INTO @table(col2) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

This will show `(4 row(s) affected)`

Now what I want:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @table TABLE(col1 INT IDENTITY(1,1), col2 INT)
INSERT INTO @table(col2) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
-- do other stuff...

SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT = 666 -- return this value to client with ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Obviously `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT = 666` is incorrect syntax.

I need to set `@@ROWCOUNT` manually, and return that value to a c# client with `rowsAffected = ExecuteNonQuery(...)`

Can this be done?
(Note: I use a stored procedure, and do not want to use an OUT parameter or return a recordset)

Comment: If you want to return a value, then don't rely on using the rows affected count. Use an `OUTPUT` parameter or `SELECT 666` for example.

Comment: @DavidG, I do not want to return an OUT parameter or record-set.

Comment: Then you can't do what you want. There's no way (nor should there be) to manipulate the rows affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to create an artificial (rows affected) message is to perform an action that affects that number of rows whilst having as few side effects as possible:

```
declare @t table (n int not null)
;With Numbers (n) as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so1.object_id)
    from sys.objects so1,sys.objects so2
)
insert into @t(n) select n from Numbers where n<=666
```

Whether it will be sufficient to trick `ExecuteNonQuery` I couldn't say. (If you have an actual `Numbers` table you can use that in place of the CTE, though you may have to adjust the filtering if it contains `0` or negative numbers)

Comment: This is awful though, a waste of server resources for no real reason.

Comment: Actually in my database it says `(100 row(s) affected)` b/c `select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so1.object_id)
    from sys.objects so1,sys.objects so2` returned on 100 rows. and yes I agree this is an awful  **solution**.

Comment: @zig - you can add more cross joins of `sys.objects` to multiply up the number of rows in `Numbers`. You must be working in a tiny database at the moment (I ran in a DB with ~10 tables, 5 stored procs, 1 view, most objects with 5 columns or less and I got a 666 message)

Comment: @DavidG - sometimes one has to do terrible things, such as here where I'm probably using an extra page in tempdb for a few milliseconds. If the OP is only able to manipulate the contents of a stored procedure, say, and is unable to change the calling code which is known to be using `ExecuteNonQuery` and can't have additional params added,...

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I guess there is no other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Do stuff
SET NOCOUNT OFF
-- Run the actual query that will affect the specified number of rows
SET NOCOUNT ON
-- Do more stuff
```

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Example1
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @table TABLE(col1 INT IDENTITY(1,1), col2 INT)
    INSERT INTO @table(col2) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
SET NOCOUNT OFF
    SELECT a.*
    INTO #NoWhere
    FROM @table AS a
        CROSS JOIN @table AS b
SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM @table AS a
        CROSS JOIN @table AS b
GO;
EXEC Example1
-- (16 row(s) affected)
```